# Only MouseUp (and not MouseDown) changing text in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce

I have a textbox that specifies whether something is an outlier. Meaning that if a mouse event (MouseUp or MouseDown) is in one panel (background) it is an outlier, whereas if a mouse event (MouseUp or MouseDown) happens in a foreground panel, then it is not an outlier. When the MouseDown event happens, it changes the values in the textbox, but when the MouseUp event happens the value in the textbox.

The functionality I am trying to create is clicking down in the background panel (so that the textbox says "Outlier") and then holding the mouse button down so that the MouseUp event happens in the foreground (so that the textbox now says "Not Outlier").

However when I try my code I only get the first part of the functionality, even when the other stuff happens. My code is below:

additionally here are my layers:

Form : "MainOuterForm"

---- Panel : "OuterPanel"

-------- Panel : "InnerPanel"

```
    public Form1(){

        InitializeComponent();

        this.textBox1.BringToFront();
        this.OuterPanel.MouseUp += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { OnMouseEvent_UpDown(sender); };
        this.OuterPanel.MouseDown += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { OnMouseEvent_UpDown(sender); };
        this.textBox1.BringToFront();
        this.InnerPanel.MouseUp += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { OnMouseEvent_UpDown(sender); };
        this.InnerPanel.MouseDown += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { OnMouseEvent_UpDown(sender); };

    }

    private void OnMouseEvent_UpDown(object sender, Point mouseLoc, MouseState mouseState){

        textBox1.Text = checkOutlier(sender) ? "Outlier" : "Not Outlier";

    }

    private bool checkOutlier(object sender){

        return ((Control)sender).Parent.ToString().Equals("MainOuterForm") ? true : false;

    }
```

Comment: The mouse is captured by the MouseDown panel until it is released.

Comment: @Jimi where do I specify that option?

Comment: [ReleaseCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-releasecapture). In the `MouseDown` event of the Outer panel.

Comment: You can also use the `Control.Capture` property: `var ctl = sender as Control; ctl.Capture = false;`. Same event. It uses the same Win32 function (`ReleaseCapture`), but it's not exactly the same. It can work, though.